# GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Could you please help me on this error. I am using below versions

- Google Map SDK for iOS v1.10.1
- Xcode v6.4
- Cocoapods v0.38.2

and Other Linker Flags set to `$(inherited)` as advised by Cocoapods.
Also note that I have set delegate to self and class inherited GMSMapViewDelegate protocol.

Please advise.

```
2015-07-28 21:14:11.876 GoogleMapsIssueTest[9719:384475] -[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd864018d00
2015-07-28 21:14:11.881 GoogleMapsIssueTest[9719:384475] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd864018d00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b9f4c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d59abb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b9fc0ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b95213c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b951cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   GoogleMapsIssueTest                 0x0000000109ce6308 -[GMSMapView setCamera:] + 151
    6   GoogleMapsIssueTest                 0x0000000109ce4c9b -[GMSMapView sharedInitWithServices:camera:forPlaces:] + 2329
    7   GoogleMapsIssueTest                 0x0000000109ce3be6 -[GMSMapView initWithCoder:] + 71
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c56c24b -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 205
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c6bd956 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 705
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c6bd68c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 276
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010c56be44 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 153
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010c6bd956 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 705
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010c6bdb25 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1168
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010c6bd68c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 276
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010c56b2e7 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 990
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010c3c36d8 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010c3c3cc8 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010c3c3f39 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010c3c43ce -[UIViewController view] + 27
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010c2df289 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010c2df64f -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010c2ebde1 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010c28f417 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2732
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010c29219e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010c291095 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    26  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111a215e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b92841c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b91e165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b91df25 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b91d366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010c290b02 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010c2938c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    33  GoogleMapsIssueTest                 0x0000000109b557a7 main + 135
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010dcd0145 start + 1
    35  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is code sample

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var googleHistoryMapView: GMSMapView!

    var googleHistoryMapCamera: GMSCameraPosition!
    var googleHistoryDrivePath: GMSMutablePath!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        googleHistoryMapCamera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 16)
        googleHistoryMapView.animateToCameraPosition(googleHistoryMapCamera)

        googleHistoryMapView.delegate = self

        googleHistoryMapView.myLocationEnabled = false
        googleHistoryMapView.trafficEnabled = true
        googleHistoryMapView.indoorEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code, otherwise it's hard to help

Comment: Thanks Vincze. I have added code now for your advise

Comment: Where does the error come from? I can not see you calling [GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:] anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks again Vincze. I have tried with -ObjC but failed and I am getting this error which I have added in my post

Comment: Even I have tried both together -ObjC and $(inherited) and no luck. Please help me.

Comment: If you are using cocoapods, you shouldnt need to change $(inherited) in your Other Linker Flag. Make sure you follow all the steps in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#step_3_install_the_api_using_cocoapods). Or you can upload your sample project to github.

Comment: Hi Ztan. I just uploaded my test project for your advise and have followed documentation and I could see same error. https://github.com/dhamukrish/GoogleMapsTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed now with below updates and Podfile can now have `use_frameworks!`

- Updated Cocoapods to 0.38.2 ( I guess issue is fixed here)
- Added `-ObjC` in `Other Linker Flags` along with `$(inherited)`

Thanks for all your support

Comment: I have updated Cocoapods and added -ObjC in Linker Flag but still my app crashes if I try to call any GMSMapView method say .animate(toLocation: location), .animate(toZoom: 17) or .delegate. My Question if you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72196016/google-map-gmsmapview-crashes-on-animatetolocation

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing $(inherited) in Other Linker Flags with "-ObjC".